# How to bind keys in dialog?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to build wizard dialog based on `NewSourceModulePage` and `NewSourceModuleWizard` classes (DLTK).

I don't know how to bind some key to activate textfields and other elements of dialog. In basic `SourceModulePage` I get two elements: "Source Folder" and "Name".

When I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, I can change the source folder, with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> I can the "Browse" button.

How can I obtain this effect for other elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse automatically picks up certain strings and uses these as accelerators. But not on all platforms - e.g. this is not supported on Mac OS X.

You can control the accelerators by including "&" (ampersand) on the strings for tabs in tab-folders and the lead-in labels for controls that can have focus - e.g. Text and Table.

Comment: Thank you, it all about ampersand.